# Como forzar a escribir solo mayúsculas en un input, en ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Mi problema NO es para guardar el valor en mayúsculas, lo que quiero hacer es que mientras el usuario escriba solo se vean mayúsculas, es decir, así el teclado se encuentre en minúsculas, en PANTALLA, se vean mayúsculas, es mas algo visual...Gracias.

Comment: string = "hola"
string.upcase!
string   #=> "HOLA"

Comment: <input style="text-transform:uppercase" > </input> Agregando este tipo de estilo igual al momento de guardar almacena en minúscula el texto como puedo hacer que respete el estilo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para esto existe una propiedad de css que le puedes asignar al input.
La propiedad es
 text-transform: uppercase;
y basta con que lo agregues a la clase que maneja tu input o directamente sobre el input

```html
<input style="text-transform:uppercase" > </input>
```

Saludos espero te sirva

Answer (score 2):

Para efectos visuales está bien:

```
<input style="text-transform:uppercase" > </input>
```

Pero si intentas guardar en la base de datos, guardará todo en minúscula.

Te recomiendo uses mejor lo siguiente:

```
onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Entonces el problema no esta relacionado directamente a ruby on rails, ya que este opera a nivel de servidor, lo que quieres hacer es una interacción a nivel de front end, para esto tienes otras herramientas como javascript, se me ocurre que puedes escuchar el evento keyup o keyrelease del teclado sobre el control y reaccionar sobre el, en función a la tecla presionada, si es mayúscula imprimirla sino solo dejarla pasar.

```js
    $("#inputUpCase").keydown(function(event) {
            // Allow only backspace and delete
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
                // let it happen, dont do anything
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is not a mayus and stop the keypress
                if (event.keyCode < 65 || event.keyCode > 90 ) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }   
            }
        });
```

Comment: Coincido con joel tu problema puede ser solucionado con JS.